# AngularJS - Check user/password in Login Service using md5 Password

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, authentication

I have created a login using angularjs - i am simply trying to pass it to my service user.php to check the credentials and then forward after authenticated. Problem is, is my password is ecrytped using md5 and im trying to figure out how to add this encoding into my data being sent from the service.

**login form - login.html**

```
    <div class="bs-example">
    <form role="form" name="form1">
    <div class="pgelogo"></div><p></p>
       <div class="form-group">
       <p>Welcome : <span>{{user.userid}}</span></p>
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Userid</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"  class="form-control" 
          ng-model="user.userid" required>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"
          id="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-control" ng-model="user.pass" 
             required>
       </div>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="login(user)" 
           ng-disabled="form1.$invalid">Submit</button>
          <p>{{msgtxt}}</p>
   </form>
   </div>
```

**controller - loginctrl.js**

```
    'use strict';

     app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','loginService', 
        function ($scope,loginService) {
$scope.msgtxt='';
$scope.login=function(data){
    loginService.login(data,$scope); //call login service
   };
    }]);
```

**directive - logindrc.js**

```
    'use strict';
          app.directive('loginDirective',function(){
 return{
    templateUrl:'partials/tpl/login.tpl.html'
   }
     });
```

**service - loginservice.js**

```
   'use strict';
    app.factory('loginService',function($http, $location, sessionService){
return{
    login:function(data,scope){
        var $promise=$http.post('data/user.php',data); 
                     //send data to user.php
        $promise.then(function(msg){
            var uid=msg.data;
            var pass=msg.data;
            if(uid && pass){
                //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                sessionService.set('uid',uid);
                //sessionService.set('lvl',level);
                $location.path('/home');
            }          
            else  {
                scope.msgtxt='incorrect information';
                $location.path('/login');
            }                  
        });
    },
    logout:function(){
        sessionService.destroy('uid');
        //sessionService.destroy('lvl');
        $location.path('/login');
    },
    islogged:function(){
        var $checkSessionServer=$http.post('data/check_session.php');
        return $checkSessionServer;
        /*
        if(sessionService.get('user')) return true;
        else return false;
        */
    }
       }
          });
```

****user.php - checks user authentication**

```
          ini_set("display_errors",1); 
          error_reporting(E_ALL);

         //connect to db
          require "../protected/db.php";

         //$user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

           $user = $_SESSION['uid']=uniqid('ang_');
         //$user   = $_POST['uid'];
           $pass   = md5($_POST['pass']));

           session_start();

          if(isset($user) && isset($pass)) 
          {
         //get userid and level from users table according to 
           username and password entered
          $sql = "SELECT userid,lvl FROM dbo.users WHERE userid = ? AND psw = ?";

          $params = array($user, $pass);

      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params);

     //if query does not work, return false
      if($stmt === false){
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }

        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row)
           {
              do{
        //store users session for angular to handle
         $_SESSION['uid']=uniqid('ang_');
         $_SESSION['level'] = $row['lvl'];

      //update the userlogin table with active user sesssion
       $rec = "INSERT INTO dbo.user_login (
                user_id,
                time)
                VALUES 
                (?,getdate())";

        $recparams = array($user);
        $s = sqlsrv_query($conn,$rec,$recparams);

       if( $s === false )
        {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

                   } while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt ) );
                 }   

               session_destroy();
               }
```

I am able to authenticate with just simple username password but i need the password to be encoded to check against the values in my db. I am getting error 500 service error meaning something is happening on the server end... just can't pin point it. Any help with this would be appreciated by any of you angularjs masters.

Comment: Send the password over in cleartext and hash it on the server, then compare the two hashed values on the server for equality

Comment: md5 is broken, dont even bother

Comment: I guess, my question is also how would i seperate the username and password in my controller to send to the service? Right now, its grouping the password and i can't seem to authenticate at all.

Comment: Also, as far as passwords, many of our users use passwords that contain special characters. like "M#gIC!" so i will need some way to encode it. I used "htmlspecialchars" and it displays the username correctly but how would i check against those passwords using my angular service?

Comment: I use http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ to perform an MD5 Hash on text in the browser.

Comment: "MD5 is a secure hash algorithm." nope, its not

Answer (score 2):

Integrate this module: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-md5

On the login form: login form - login.html

```
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"
     id="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-control" ng-model="pass" required>
```

And then on the controller: controller - loginctrl.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','md5','loginService', function ($scope,md5,loginService) {
    $scope.$watch('pass', function() {
        $scope.user.pass = md5.createHash($scope.pass || '');
    });
    ...
}]);
```

So this solved the issue in my case